# addEventListener doesn't add listener to element

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener

I have the next code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    var dropZone = document.getElementById("dropZone");
    dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver);
    dropZone.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop);
    console.log(dropZone);
  }
};
```

The problem is that addEventListener doesn't add any listener to the dropZone object. So when I check dropZone object in console log the "ondragover" and "ondrop" properties are empty.

I tried to use readyState "complete" instead of "interactive" but it doesn't work too. When I try to add this listeners to body element it's work fine (listeners are added and all handling functions work).

I can't figure out what the problem is. So please anyone give me advice in what direction I should look.

Comment: Is your handleDragOver and handleDrop function preventing default?

Comment: How do you check the properties? `dropZone.ondragover` is most likely still `null` but in Firefox for example there are little “ev” boxes next to elements in the page inspector view. These indicate which event listeners an element has. For exmaple, on StackOverlow `document.body` has two `mousedown` events and three `click` events, although both `document.body.onclick` and `document.body.onmousedown` are `null`.

Comment: [Try this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).

Comment: Is the dropZone element in the HTML of your page?  Or, is it dynamically added via some code?  Have you tried just putting the event listener adding code at the end of your page (without the readystatechange code)?  Are you 100% sure there is only one element in your page with an id of dropZone?  `addEventListener()` does not set `ondragover` and `ondrop` so it is normal that they are empty.

Comment: Probably this won't fix your issue, but using `document.onreadystatechange` is not a good idea as you can get more than 1 listener registered. I'd recommend to change it to `window.onload`

Comment: I tried to get the readystate thing to work reliably for ages, and finally gave up; now I just check whether the element I want to manipulate exists already, and if not, re-check after the DOMcontentloaded event. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will try to find the dropZone element, and if it's not already loaded, try again after the DOM is fully loaded. This should work wherever your script is (head, start of body, end of body, external file, asynchronously loaded...)

```js
function activateDropZone() {
    var dropZone = document.getElementById("dropZone");
    if (dropZone) {
        dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
        dropZone.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
    } else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", activateDropZone, false);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("dropZone").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("dropZone").style.backgroundColor = "violet";
    document.getElementById("draggable").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

activateDropZone();
```

```css
DIV {float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue; color: white;}
DIV:last-of-type {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
```

```html
<DIV ID="dropZone">dropzone</DIV>
<DIV ID="draggable" draggable="true">draggable</DIV>
```

Comment: Hm, the example doesn't seem to work when run as a code snippet here... oh well.